# separate javascript modular and load externally may cause lower performance?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to improve my website performance.
but https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_performance.asp says

> The HTTP specification defines that browsers should not download more
>   than two components in parallel.

So my question: does separate javascript modular and load externally possibly cause lower performance? or modular style code cause lower performance?

Comment: I think performance differs from initial load, that being said, is there a reason why you mix the two, and not have a bundler combine everything into 1 big package?

Comment: agree @Icepickle

Comment: It's open source project so i'm aiming for high accessibility. modular style coding is really helps me while developing. and i'm using external script like jquery, wiper kind things so i couldn't decide easily,,,

Comment: I see your point but given a good bundler (eg: webpack), you could bundle the external resources into a `vendor.js` file, and your module as part of the `app.js`. I think your question as it is now, is not specific enough to give a good answer to

Comment: Okay I'm sorry. I'll more carefool next time. I think you are right.

Comment: @mplungjan also thanks to correct my grammar!